# How to set NSMutableString to null?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
NSMutableString *str;
```

//I have already done the allocation etc

Suppose this `str` has some value.
I set `str=@""` it shows a `warning`. How to set the NSMutableString as Null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `str = nil`?

You should also `[str release]` first in order to free the memory used by the current string.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to just set it to an empty string, do the following:

NSMutableString *str;

// append some strings
// ...

[str setString:@""];

Otherwise, if you want to release it and set it to null:

[str release], str = nil;

Note: Constant strings like @"" uses special strings refs.  You can look into this further, but its not actually allocating a new string every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str = nil;`

But in almost all cases, I would probably recommend you use `NSString` instead of `NSMutableString`. When you assign your str variable @"", that is instantiating a new empty string (`NSString`), and assigning it to str, hence the type error.

It is almost always easier to just create a new string from your old string using something like `[NSString stringByAppendingString:@" new string content"]` or `[NSString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ stuff %@", otherString1, otherString2]`.